# Question on a proof about gradients over expectations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For well-defined $h(z)$, discrete probability distribution $Q_\theta(z)$ parameterized by $\theta$, the claim is that:

$$\nabla_{\theta}\mathbb{E}_{z\sim Q_\theta(z)}[h(z)] = \mathbb{E}_{z \sim Q_\theta(z)}[\nabla_{\theta}[\log Q_\theta(z)]h(z)].$$

To prove this claim, we proceed as follows.

(1) Pick an arbitrary distribution $\rho$ over $z$, discrete, such that $Q_\theta(z)/\rho(z)$ is finite.

(2) Then $$\mathbb E_{z\sim Q_\theta}[h(z)] = \sum_{z\in\mathcal Z} h(z) Q_\theta(z) \cdot \frac{\rho(z)}{\rho(z)} = \mathbb E_{z\sim \rho}[h(z) \frac{Q_\theta(z) }{\rho(z)}] $$

(3) Since the $z$s are discrete we can easily take the gradient:
$$\nabla_\theta \mathbb E_{z\sim Q_\theta}[h(z)] = \mathbb E_{z\sim \rho}[h(z) \frac{\nabla_\theta Q_\theta(z) }{\rho(z)}] $$

(4) Since $\rho$ was arbitary, set it to $Q_{\theta}$ and then recall that:

$$\nabla_\theta \left[\log Q_\theta(z) \right]  = \frac{\nabla_\theta Q_\theta(z) }{Q_\theta(z)}$$

However, I was thinking: since $\rho$ was arbitrary, why not just choose $\rho = Q_\theta$ from the start? But if I do that, by step (3), if I take the gradient in the inside, I must apply the quotient rule, giving me a gradient of $0$. Where is the error in my understanding?